# Custom Automatic Redirects in Flask

Tags: python, rest, redirect, flask

I am using Flask to build a ReST/JSON API. I want all of my responses to be JSON, even when they're error responses.

I have already made my app return uniform JSON responses for successful operations and most errors. Here's the relevant portion of my code:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from werkzeug import exceptions

app = Flask(__name__)

def make_json_response(status, message, content):
    """Function to generate uniform JSON responses across the API"""
    response = {
        "api_version": __version__,
        "content": content,  # The data the API is supposed to return
        "message": message,  # Content description, error message, etc.
        "request_id": g.get("request_id", None),
        "status": status,  # HTTP Status
    }
    return jsonify(response), status


def json_error_handler(error=exceptions.InternalServerError, message=None):
    """Makes JSON error messages. By default, Flask will return HTML error 
    messages, but we want this API to return valid JSON even on errors."""
    return make_json_response(
        status=error.code, message=message or error.description, content=None)


# Registering JSON error handlers for each HTTP error that we might reasonably throw.
# Covers 400, 401, 403, 404, 405, 406, 408, 409, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 415, 416, 417, 418, 422, 428, 429, 431, 500, 501, 502, 503, 504, 505
for error_class in exceptions.default_exceptions.values():
    app.register_error_handler(error_class, json_error_handler)
```

So that's all working. However, 300-3XX responses are not addressed. From what I can tell, redirect errors are not `raise`d in the same way that the other errors are. For example, a 500 may strike at any time when there's a bug in my code, but 300s are a routing decision, and happen before my code is reached.

Flask very helpfully generates automatic redirect responses. For example, if a user tries to GET `/jobs`, but the real path is `/jobs/`, Flask will reply with a redirect with no additional work on my end:

```
$ curl -i https://api.example.com/jobs
HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY
Server: gunicorn/19.6.0
Date: Thu, 01 Jun 2017 14:40:18 GMT
X-Cnection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: http://api.example.com/jobs/
Content-Length: 295

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>Redirecting...</title>
<h1>Redirecting...</h1>
<p>You should be redirected automatically to target URL: <a href="http://api.example.com/jobs/">http://api.example.com/jobs/</a>.  If not click the link.
```

This is desirable behavior. The only issue is that the generated response does not conform to the JSON response pattern used by the rest of the API's responses. This could cause clients that are expecting JSON responses to explode. (Now, any client brittle enough to have that issue should really know the correct URIs to begin with, but still, I would like my API responses to be uniform and helpful.)

From what I can tell, behind the scenes, Flask uses [werkzeug.utils.redirect](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/utils/#werkzeug.utils.redirect) to generate the redirect, but I don't see an obvious way to monkey-patch my own redirect function into my Flask app.

Is there a way to change the automatically-generated Flask redirect responses?

Comment: Have you tried to use `response.mimetype = 'application/json'`?

Comment: @Nurzhan In what context? I don't generate the 301 response anywhere in my code, Flask does it for me automatically.